# Rails: How to replace ENV['USERNAME'] with actual username info?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a quick question about rails. I keep seeing ENV['SOMETHING'] and am not sure how to replace the actual variable with that. Do I just replace 'SOMETHING' with 'my_value' so that ENV['SOMETHING'] becomes ENV['my_value'] ? I read somewhere that you have to change it in your bash profile, but how would I go about doing that?

Here's an example of where it would show up:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "railscasts.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to be able to set ENV variable with plain:

```
ENV['your_var'] = your_value
```

And then access it via:

```
ENV['your_var']
```

You can make the actual settings on config/environments/development.rb or any other init file you wish.